# How can I view the status code of a closed connection in Python websocket?

Tags: python, websocket

I wrote a simple websocket client in Python, following is the code (on_error and on_message definitions are omitted for readability reasons):

```
import websocket

def on_close(self, ws):
    print("Websocket closed")

self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://url...",
                                 on_message = on_message,
                                 on_error = on_error,
                                 on_close = on_close)
```

I would like to add the close reason/status code to the print statement in the `on_close()` method, but I cannot find a way to access this information.
Is there a way to access this information?

Comment: ... python has no built-in websockets. Which library are you using?

Comment: I'm using websocket (import websocket). I'll update the code in the example

Comment: That's [`websocket-client`](https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/), correct?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Have you tried the [`WebSocket.status`](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/66081be8e0523c9dfaffcb18ba1c8e4765e2288e/websocket/_core.py#L170) property?

Comment: @shmee WebSocketApp doesn't have this property

Comment: Does `ws.status` give you something?

Comment: @omer Oh, I missed that this is a `WebSocketApp` instance. But that one does have an attribute `sock` that holds a `WebSocket` instance.

Comment: @shmee, couldn't find the WeSocket attribute you mentioned. I printed vars(ws.sock) and it does not appear there.

Comment: @omer Of course not :) A property is not a writable attribute. `dir(ws.sock)` should show it, plus a lot more.

Comment: @shmee The status is 101, it is the status of the 'switching protocols' in http. It does not provide information about the close status code :/

Comment: The [docstring on the `_get_close_args`](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/66081be8e0523c9dfaffcb18ba1c8e4765e2288e/websocket/_app.py#L322-L323) method mentions the invokation of the `on_close` callback with the *code* and *reason* extracted from the current frame if the opcode is *close*. The signature of that callback should look somewhat like this: `def on_close(ws, code, reason):`. Maybe that gives you the desired data.